# Amenability of a covering group

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, amenability

Suppose $F$ is a nonabelian free group and $F/N_1$ and $F/N_2$ are amenable groups. Does it follow that $F/(N_1 \cap N_2)$ is amenable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F/N_1\cap N_2$ embeds into the product $F/N_1 \times F/N_2$ under the natural map.  Since the class of amenable groups is closed under products and passing to subgroups, we see that $F/N_1\cap N_2$ is indeed amenable.